# Odd behaviour when comparing Java and Jython types

Tags: java, jython, primitive-types, comparison-operators, jython-2.7

Why do I experience the following behaviour when comparing a Java integer to a Python one of the same value in Jython?

```py
>>> from java.lang import Integer
>>> 10 == Integer(10)
False
>>> 10 <= Integer(10)
True
>>> 10 >= Integer(10)
True
```

Okay, so I find it weird that both `<=` and `>=` operators evaluate as expected, yet `==` does not... So now lets check implicit conversions between Java & Jython types:

```
>>> i = Integer(10)
>>> i == 10
False
```

What about other Java classes I hear you say? Lets try:

```
>>> from java.lang import Boolean
>>> Boolean(0) == False
False
>>> Boolean(0) == True
False
>>> Boolean(0)  # lets just check it is a Java false not a Python one
false
```

Am I missing something or is it just as simple as the `__eq__` magic (dunder) methods are broken for the Java classes (I am using Jython 2.7)?

**EDIT**

Thanks to [weston](https://stackoverflow.com/users/360211/weston) for clarifying that in java `10 == new Integer(10)` evaluates as `true` and therefore the question is not a duplicate of [What is the difference between == vs equals() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between == vs equals() in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java)

Comment: Not a duplicate, that question does not explain this because this behavior is not seen in java `10 == new Integer(10)` is true in java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essentially it's because `==` compares *references* for boxed types, not the actual values.

But to muddy the waters further `<=` and `>=` will auto-unbox any boxed operands.

Comment: So where only one side is boxed, jython `==` will box the other side, unlike java which unboxes the boxed side. Of course that would explain the behavior, but do you have a reference?

Comment: jython.org: ["these operators have no significant difference to that of Java."](http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/OpsExpressPF.html#comparison-operators) Seems odd then that this departure is not noteworthy.